# Reuse Apache Beam Workflow Graph

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, amazon-emr

I'm using Apache Beam to run Batch pipelines on Flink, running on AWS EMR.

Beam Pipelines are being created and submitted to a long running Flink cluster. However, I see that there is a cost associated with building the job graph and submitting it to EMR, taking constantly in excess of 2 minutes.

I want to reduce this time & was wondering if there is a way to cache/prevent Beam from building pipelines with every run of the Driver cronjob.

The job graph is a bit complex, so the 2 minute time is justified. Just looking at ways to reduce/eliminate it from happening everytime.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a breakdown of where the cost actually is, e.g. is it in pipeline construction, translation, or actually submitting it to EMR? Or is it re-uploading dependencies (e.g. jar files) each time?

Comment: The cost is around 30-40 seconds in pipeline construction & rest in submitting to EMR

Comment: I don't know how to speed up submitting to EMR, though my first hunch would be to see if there are redundant artifacts that get uploaded each time.

Comment: For pipeline construction, you could see if there are computations that could be cached/amortized across calls. Beam pipeline construction itself should be pretty fast (graphs with thousands of PTransforms should still be sub-second).